# Difference in Accept-Language and navigator.languages

Tags: google-chrome, microsoft-edge, chromium, multilingual, http-accept-language

According to [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/languages),

> The Accept-Language HTTP header in every HTTP request from the user's browser uses the same value for the navigator.languages property except for the extra qvalues (quality values) field (e.g. en-US;q=0.8).

and [spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/system-state.html#dom-navigator-languages-dev)

> To avoid introducing any more fingerprinting vectors, user agents should use the same list for the APIs defined in this function as for the HTTP `Accept-Language` header.

while adding `en-US` without `en` language, two values are different.

navigator.languages

```
['en-US']
```

accept-languages

```
en-US,en;q=0.9
```

I am using
Microsoft Edge
Version 103.0.1264.49 (Official build) (64-bit)

Is this a normal behavior or it's a bug of microsoft edge?

---

I have even tested in the latest chrome and firefox.

chrome behaves exact the same as edge because they are using the same engine.

Firefox is working perfect and same as the doc stated. `Accept-Language` and `navigator.languages` are the same.

it seems it is a bug of chromium.

Comment: If you've tested it the right way, I suggest you can report this issue. Just refer to this link: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/list

Comment: @XudongPeng reported. was thinking if it is my misunderstanding or what.